# filtering logcat timestamp in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python. I  was wondering  how I could diff the two logcat timestamp intervals and the x and y coordinates from the below logcat msg.

I have a file with the following msg from the logcat where they are represented as follows

```
Date    Time(HH:MM::SS:MS)  ACTION_TYPE, (X,Y)                              
05-03 12:53:15.251 ACTION_MOVE, (596.00, 841.00) 
05-03 12:53:15.268 ACTION_MOVE, (599.00, 847.00)
```

I would like to get the output as in the csv file

```
timestampdiff(millsec), x_change,y_change
17,3.00,6.00
```

Comment: have you tried anything? Do you know how to read a file in Python? stored in specified character encoding? line by line? Do you know regular expressions? Do you know how to parse a time string in a specified format? Do you know how to parse a string that contain a float number in Python? Do you know how to iterate pairwise in Python? Do you know how to write to a csv file a list of tuple such as `[(17, 3.0, 6.0)]`?

Comment: Do all lines in the log file have the format you described? If so you can easily split the lines on significant positions and convert the date-time-strings into a [https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html](datetime) object and  use `(date1 - date2).microseconds / 1000` for your milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to parse the file (once you [read it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3277516/6297253))

```
import re

# example string from your file
s='05-03 12:53:15.251 ACTION_MOVE, (596.00, 841.00) '

# The unescaped round brackets will capture the numbers 
r =re.match(r'\d+-\d+\s+\d+:\d+:(\d+\.\d+)\s+[A-Z_]+,\s+\(\d+\.\d+,\s+\d+\.\d+\)', s)

r.groups(0)  # Will output ('15.251',)
```

Repeat the above for all numbers that you need, convert to decimal (or float) and calculate the difference.

Comment: Thanks this works !!   after using  r = re.match(r'\d+-\d+\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\.(\d+)', s) and then seetting    currtime = (int(r.group(1)) * 24 * 60 + int(r.group(2)) * 60 + int(r.group(3))) * 1000 + int(r.group(4))  outputs cuurent time in ms.